# Import plugin error logs

Tags: plugins, import, plugin-import

I'm using the import plugin from Bob Olde Hampsink and I've got a exported .csv file. There's nothing special in it but I can't seem to import. I know there's an error log somewhere, but I can't seem to find it. Does anyone know where it's situated? I've found it once but now I'm totally lost and can't seem to find an answer somewhere...

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Craft 2 the log files are usually stored in craft/storage/runtime/logs/ and named after the plugin handle.

If the Import plugin does nothing special, you should find its logs in craft/storage/runtime/logs/import.log

Comment: So it looks like I was looking in the right place, but there's no error log for the import plugin in there... And in the history I only get the error that there's something wrong in line 2 of the .csv file. I've tried not importing some fields, but that didn't help either...